# Submitting multiple forms in one transaction

Tags: cognito-forms

We'd like to give customers a discount for submitting multiple forms at once.

Is there a way to do this?

Maybe a cart option?

Comment: By the way, I mean submitting form A multiple times with different data.  I don't mean submitting form A and form B.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment Form A would not be able to know if it has multiple entries from the same user or email address. I think that this feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/vKfb0oVP) would be able to help you with what you are looking to set up.

You might want to take a look at the [Repeating Section field](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/40/building-forms/form-field-reference/repeating-section). This can give your users the ability to submit multiple orders for items and then get a discount based on how many they order.